# Json formatting for Google cloud NLP API (documents.analyzeEntities)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-natural-language

To send a document to the Cloud NLP API, we use the below JSON formating (as per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/documents/analyzeEntities) )

```
{
"document":{
            "type":"PLAIN_TEXT",
            "content":"Joanne Rowling, who writes under the pen names J. K. Rowling and Robert Galbraith, is a British novelist and screenwriter who wrote the Harry Potter fantasy series. i am suffering without resolution.only communication coming about fees without knowledge of card.wrist ever banking experience."
},
"encodingType":"UTF8"
}
```

This format works perfectly for the curl command i'm using.

```
curl "https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntities?key=${API_KEY}" -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @request.json
```

However if want to add more than one document, how do i do it? I tried several ways, like making a List of dicts under 'document'. But it doesn't work. One of the attempt is shown below.

```
{
"document":{[{
            "type":"PLAIN_TEXT",
            "content":"Joanne Rowling, who writes under the pen names J. K. Rowling and Robert Galbraith, is a British novelist and screenwriter who wrote the Harry Potter fantasy series. i am suffering without resolution.only communication coming about fees without knowledge of card.wrist ever banking experience."
            },
            {
            "type":"PLAIN_TEXT",
            "content":"Joanne Rowling, who writes under the pen names J. K. Rowling and Robert Galbraith, is a British novelist and screenwriter who wrote the Harry Potter fantasy series. i am suffering without resolution.only communication coming about fees without knowledge of card.wrist ever banking experience."
            }
            ]},
"encodingType":"UTF8"
}
```

I get errors like

```
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected an object key or }.\n{\n\"document\":{[\n                {\"\n              ^",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, the Cloud Natural Language API doesn't not accept multiple documents requests. You have to group in one text or send multiple requests.
There is already a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135525754) for this to be implemented.
Don't hesitate to add comments about your use case in order to let the product engineering team know about it.